# Bulk auto NEF → TIFF in RawTherapee?

Tags: raw, batch, tiff, rawtherapee, open-source

Is there a way in RawTherapee (or another open-source app) to automatically bulk export NEFs to TIFFs using the camera's built-in options? I'd like to generate TIFFs using the exact same options the camera itself uses to generate JPEGs for each NEF it takes.

Comment: If you have access to Windows or Mac, you could use Nikon's own software - [NX Studio](https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/index.html) - which will do this almost by default. It knows *exactly* what the camera settings were, no reverse-engineering/guesswork required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "the camera's built-in options", I assume you mean "camera's color profile".

You can find [DCP profiles](https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/Color_Management#DCP) for your specific camera in the `$HOME/wine-dng/drive_c/ProgramData/CameraRaw/Settings/Adobe/Profiles/Camera/` directory of [Adobe's DNG Converter for Windows](https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/using/adobe-dng-converter.html), where `wine-dng` is the [`wine64`](https://www.winehq.org/) install directory (`$WINEPREFIX`) on Linux (cf. [the RawTherapee wiki](https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/How_to_get_LCP_and_DCP_profiles#Linux)); for Windows, cf. [these instructions](https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/How_to_get_LCP_and_DCP_profiles#Windows).

Load the DCP file for your camera as a custom [Color Management Input Profile](https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/Color_Management#Input_Profile).
You can also click the [Auto-Matched Tone Curve](https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/Exposure#Auto-Matched_Tone_Curve) button in the Exposure panel, to "adjust sliders and curves (except exposure compensation) to match the look of the embedded JPEG thumbnail."

Then you can do [Copy & Paste Batch Adjustments](https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/Batch_Adjustments_-_Sync#Copy_&_Paste) to apply this color profile to multiple images, add them to [the queue](https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/Queue), and generate TIFFs.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no, at least not entirely. But Nikons free NX Studio software will do it quite easily. AFAIK, it is the only software that recognizes and applies every jpeg camera setting to the raw files. Batch export as tiff is also a simple process.

Comment: I'd like an open-source solution. Thanks.

Comment: There is no open source solution that can do this *properly*. The algorithms used by Nikon are not published, so everybody else has to try reverse-engineer them, with varying degrees of accuracy.

Comment: The software running on the camera is closed-source, as are the development algorithms. Just saying.